# Null-invariant measures of association in R

Tags: data-mining, r

A usual way to find association rules in R is the "arules" package, which easily let's use calculate some rules based on the apriori algorithm.

However, for the data i'm using, I have a lot of NULL cases (baskets where no product A o B is present). This means that I need to calculate some null-invariant measures (kulcynski, for instance).

Does anyone know of any package or workable code that let's me implement this as opposed to writing from scratch the entire algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

interestMeasure function from arules v1.5-5 let’s you find additional measures and also some invariant ones. Here’s the link to the R documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.5-5/topics/interestMeasure